# Timeline javascript modificación

Tags: javascript

estoy intentado modificar este timeline para que pueda añadir mas elementos pero cuando añado un elemento mas todo se descoloca.
El javascript del que parto: https://codepen.io/meric-fournier/pen/WGOLXb

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".parcours-box").removeClass("parcours-active");


  $(".round1").on("click", function() {
    $(".tl-round").css("background-color", "rgb(85, 69, 69)");
    $(".round1").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".parcours-active").removeClass("parcours-active");
    $(".parc1").addClass("parcours-active");
    $(".timeline-indicator").css("width", "0");
  })

  $(".round2").on("click", function() {
    $(".tl-round").css("background-color", "rgb(85, 69, 69)");
    $(".round1").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".round2").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".parcours-active").removeClass("parcours-active");
    $(".parc2").addClass("parcours-active");
    $(".timeline-indicator").css("width", "240");
  })

  $(".round3").on("click", function() {
    $(".tl-round").css("background-color", "rgb(85, 69, 69)");
    $(".round1").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".round2").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".round3").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".parcours-active").removeClass("parcours-active");
    $(".parc3").addClass("parcours-active");
    $(".timeline-indicator").css("width", "480");
  })

  $(".round4").on("click", function() {
    $(".tl-round").css("background-color", "rgb(85, 69, 69)");
    $(".round1").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".round2").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".round3").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".round4").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".parcours-active").removeClass("parcours-active");
    $(".parc4").addClass("parcours-active");
    $(".timeline-indicator").css("width", "720");
  })

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/EOjzXGI.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
}


/* ****** */

.timeline-parcours {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 10px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.container-info {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 187px;
}

.timeline-section-tl {
  width: 236px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.infobox {
  width: 226px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 1px;
}

.fleche-bloc {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 15px 0 15px;
  border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
  margin: auto;
}

.parcours-box {
  opacity: 0;
  z-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.container-time-line {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.time-line-parcours {
  width: 730px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #432828;
  margin: auto;
}

.timeline-indicator {
  width: 0px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(120, 131, 208);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.tl-round {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(85, 69, 69);
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.container-bulle {
  margin-top: -15px;
}


/* animation classe */

.anim-phase-1 {
  width: 240px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease;
  transition: all 100ms ease;
}

.anim-phase-2 {
  width: 475px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease;
  transition: all 100ms ease;
}

.anim-phase-3 {
  width: 720px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease;
  transition: all 100ms ease;
}

.parcours-active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="timeline-parcours">
    <div class="container-info">
      <div class="timeline-section-tl">
        <div class="parcours-box parc1">
          <div class="infobox date1">
            <h3>Titre titre 1</h3>
            <p class="subt-infobox">ceci est un test</p>
            <p class="infobox-text">ceci est un court texte d'information par rapport à un évènement</p>
          </div>
          <div class="fleche-bloc"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-section-tl">
        <div class="parcours-box parc2">
          <div class="infobox date1">
            <h3>Titre titre 2</h3>
            <p class="subt-infobox">ceci est un test</p>
            <p class="infobox-text">ceci est un court texte d'information par rapport à un évènement</p>
          </div>
          <div class="fleche-bloc"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-section-tl">
        <div class="parcours-box parc3">
          <div class="infobox date1">
            <h3>Titre titre 3</h3>
            <p class="subt-infobox">ceci est un test</p>
            <p class="infobox-text">ceci est un court texte d'information par rapport à un évènement</p>
          </div>
          <div class="fleche-bloc"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-section-tl">
        <div class="parcours-box parc4">
          <div class="infobox date1">
            <h3>Titre titre 4</h3>
            <p class="subt-infobox">ceci est un test</p>
            <p class="infobox-text">ceci est un court texte d'information par rapport à un évènement</p>
          </div>
          <div class="fleche-bloc"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-time-line">
      <div class="time-line-parcours">
        <div class="timeline-indicator">
          <p class="indicator-val"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-bulle">
      <div class="timeline-section-tl">
        <div class="tl-round round1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-section-tl">
        <div class="tl-round round2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-section-tl">
        <div class="tl-round round3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-section-tl">
        <div class="tl-round round4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
    function reste_a_faire() {
      return true;
    }

    if (reste_a_faire())
      console.log('rien n\'est fait');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

He hecho cambios en el css para que el ancho no sea fijo, pero no se que valor poner a cada elemento para que pueda ir añadiendo mas elementos y no se desconfigure todo

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* background: url(https://i.imgur.com/EOjzXGI.jpg); */
    background-color: rgba(86, 203, 249, 1);
    background-size: cover;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
}

/* ****** */
.timeline-parcours {
    width: 960px;
    /* width: auto; */
    height: auto;
    min-height: 10px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.container-info {
    width: 960px;
    /* width: auto; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 187px;
}

.timeline-section-tl {
    width: 236px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.infobox {
    width: 226px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 1px;
}

.fleche-bloc {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0 15px;
    border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
    margin: auto;
}

.parcours-box {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.container-time-line {
    width: 960px;
    /* width: auto; */
    margin: auto;
}

.time-line-parcours {
    /* width: 730px; */
    width: auto;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #432828;
    margin: auto;
}

.timeline-indicator {
    width: 0px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(120, 131, 208);
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.tl-round {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(85, 69, 69);
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.container-bulle {
    margin-top: -15px;
    /* display: inline-block; */
}

/* animation classe */

.anim-phase-1 {
    width: 240px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 100ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 100ms ease;
    transition: all 100ms ease;
}

.anim-phase-2 {
    width: 475px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 100ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 100ms ease;
    transition: all 100ms ease;
}

.anim-phase-3 {
    width: 720px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 100ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 100ms ease;
    transition: all 100ms ease;
}

.parcours-active {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

EL HTML con un elemento mas

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>test</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="timeline-parcours">
         <div class="container-info">
            <div class="timeline-section-tl">
               <div class="parcours-box parc1">
                  <div class="infobox date1">
                     <h3>Titre titre 1</h3>
                     <p class="subt-infobox">ceci est un test</p>
                     <p class="infobox-text">ceci est un court texte d'information par rapport à un évènement</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fleche-bloc"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-section-tl">
               <div class="parcours-box parc2">
                  <div class="infobox date1">
                     <h3>Titre titre 2</h3>
                     <p class="subt-infobox">ceci est un test</p>
                     <p class="infobox-text">ceci est un court texte d'information par rapport à un évènement</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fleche-bloc"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-section-tl">
               <div class="parcours-box parc3">
                  <div class="infobox date1">
                     <h3>Titre titre 3</h3>
                     <p class="subt-infobox">ceci est un test</p>
                     <p class="infobox-text">ceci est un court texte d'information par rapport à un évènement</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fleche-bloc"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-section-tl">
               <div class="parcours-box parc4">
                  <div class="infobox date1">
                     <h3>Titre titre 4</h3>
                     <p class="subt-infobox">ceci est un test</p>
                     <p class="infobox-text">ceci est un court texte d'information par rapport à un évènement</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fleche-bloc"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
           <div class="timeline-section-tl">
               <div class="parcours-box parc5">
                  <div class="infobox date1">
                     <h3>Titre titre 5</h3>
                     <p class="subt-infobox">ceci est un test</p>
                     <p class="infobox-text">ceci est un court texte d'information par rapport à un évènement</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fleche-bloc"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="container-time-line">
            <div class="time-line-parcours">
               <div class="timeline-indicator">
                  <p class="indicator-val"></p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="container-bulle">
            <div class="timeline-section-tl">
               <div class="tl-round round1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-section-tl">
               <div class="tl-round round2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-section-tl">
               <div class="tl-round round3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-section-tl">
               <div class="tl-round round4"></div>
            </div>
           <div class="timeline-section-tl">
               <div class="tl-round round5"></div>
            </div>
         </div>

      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
      <script>

         function reste_a_faire()
         {
            return true;
         }

         if(reste_a_faire())
            console.log('rien n\'est fait');

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

De momento estoy intentado añadir solo un elemento.
¿Como podria hacer para que al añadir un elemento mas la anchura de cada elemento no sea fija?
Gracias

Comment: agrega tus modificaciones en otro "fragmento de código"

Comment: Según los elementos que desees poner hay que hacer cálculos y modificar bastante los valores en el css para arreglar eso. No es un cambio liviano.  Si luego quieres agregar más elementos tendrás que recalcularlo de nuevo, a menos que el CSS sea totalmente modificado. Dices que has agregado más elementos, pero no vemos como lo has hecho, por lo tanto no vemos tus errores a corregir... ¿cuantos quieres agregar? ¿que has intentado? Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento de este sitio, gracias.

Comment: tienes razon, tendria que haber especificado mas , pero esque estoy un poco perdido en esto, ya he editado los cambios.